# PayPal multiple Currency ( IPN )?

Tags: paypal

How to use multiple currency in PayPal:

1. Setting acceptable currency on the seller account, how to?
2. How will seller IPN know if the right amount has been payed?
3. Question 1) Will the buyer see local currency then?

Thanks
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Buyers:

- Pay for purchases in your selected currency
- Payment is automatically converted to your desired currency
- No need to hold a balance in another currency to send a payment

Sellers:

- Accept payments directly in your selected currency
- Manage multiple currency payments using your current PayPal account
- Hold one currency balance and still accept payments in multiple currencies

Comment: In "Manage Currencies"... Having the "seller" primary set to EUR and set the "buyer" primary currency to EUR it shows up in USD when pressing the buy button? Hmm, I will try generating a new button....

Comment: That's because you haven't specified the currency in the button. Do that first, otherwise it'll default to USD.

Comment: So you have to create a button for each currency?